# Python regular expression string substitution

Tags: python, regex

I am interested in finding any occurrence of

```
(somenumber)
```

and replacing it with

```
-somenumber
```

I have a Perl background and tried this, hoping the (\d+) grouping would populate variable $1:

```
myterm = re.sub(r"\((\d+)\)", "-\$1",myterm)
```

However this resulted in a result of the literal

```
-$1
```

How to do this in Python?

Comment: try `r"-\1"` instead

Comment: Use a raw string: `r"-\1"` and no $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. You're using Perl's syntax (dollar sign) to dereference the positional match. Python uses `\`, not `$`.
2. Your backslash in `"-\$1` is being interpreted by the Python compiler, and is effectively removed before `re.sub` sees it.

Either using a raw string (as noted in the comments to your question), or escaping the backslash (by double-backslashing), should fix it:

```
myterm = re.sub(r"\((\d+)\)", r"-\1", myterm)
```

or

```
myterm = re.sub(r"\((\d+)\)", "-\\1", myterm)
```

Tested and confirmed:

```
import re

myterm = '(1234)'

# OP's attempt:
print re.sub(r"\((\d+)\)", "-\$1", myterm)

# two ways to fix:
print re.sub(r"\((\d+)\)", r"-\1", myterm)
print re.sub(r"\((\d+)\)", "-\\1", myterm)
```

prints:

```
-\$1
-1234
-1234
```